# Why does my function run three times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a tag cloud: When I click on a tag, the required functons runs three times, as in 3,2,1, or 2,1 instead of only one time.
This happens both on the jquery version and on plain js. What do I'm missing?
This is a very simple code, and I'm stuck on it:

```css
.cloud .weight-1 { font-size: 10px; }
.cloud .weight-2 { font-size: 25px; }
.cloud .weight-3 { font-size: 35px; }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>  
     <head>
      <title>Exercise</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2.css">
           <script type="text/javascript"
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
           </script>
     </head>
     <body>
    
       <div class="cloud">
        <div id="firstword" class="weight-1" onclick="func1()">Cloud1</a>
        <div id="secondword" class="weight-2" onclick="func2()">Cloud2</a>
        <div id="thirdword" class="weight-3" onclick="func3()">Cloud3</a>
    </div>
    
    <div>
     <foo class="bar">
      <foo id="ba"></foo>
     </foo>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
       $("#firstword").click(function()
       {
        alert("first.");
       });;
    
       $("#secondword").click(function(){
        alert("second.");
       });;
    
       $("#thirdword").click(function(){
        alert("third.");
       });;
    }); 

    /*function func3(){
     alert("3");
    };
    function func1(){
     alert("1");
    }
    ;
    function func2(){
     alert("2");
    };*/
    
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid: you open `<div>` and close `</a>`. Full html: `<div id="firstword" class="weight-1" onclick="func1()">Cloud1</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you haven't closed your divs properly.

You need to do this:

```
<div class="cloud">
    <div id="firstword" class="weight-1" onclick="func1()">Cloud1</div>
    <div id="secondword" class="weight-2" onclick="func2()">Cloud2</div>
    <div id="thirdword" class="weight-3" onclick="func3()">Cloud3</div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsFiddle to show this is all you need to change - https://jsfiddle.net/eyd5b0ku/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML close tag is not correct. Changing it will work.

```css
.cloud .weight-1 { font-size: 10px; }
.cloud .weight-2 { font-size: 25px; }
.cloud .weight-3 { font-size: 35px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    
     <head>
      <title>Exercise</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2.css">
    
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
    
       <div class="cloud">
        <div id="firstword" class="weight-1" onclick="func1()">Cloud1</div>
        <div id="secondword" class="weight-2" onclick="func2()">Cloud2</div>
             <div id="thirdword" class="weight-3" onclick="func3()">Cloud3</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
     
     <foo class="bar">
      <foo id="ba"></foo>
     </foo>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     
    $("#firstword").click(function(){
        alert("first.");
    });;
    
    $("#secondword").click(function(){
        alert("second.");
    });;
    
    $("#thirdword").click(function(){
        alert("third.");
    });;
    }); 
    function func3(){
     alert("3");
    };
    function func1(){
     alert("1");
    }
    ;
    function func2(){
     alert("2");
    };
    
    </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine now

```js
$(function() {

  $("#firstword").click(function(e) {
    alert("first.");
  });;

  $("#secondword").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("second.");
  });;

  $("#thirdword").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("third.");
  });;
});
```

```css
.cloud .weight-1 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.cloud .weight-2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.cloud .weight-3 {
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cloud">
  <div id="firstword" class="weight-1">Cloud1</a>
    <div id="secondword" class="weight-2">Cloud2</a>
      <div id="thirdword" class="weight-3">Cloud3</a>
      </div>

      <div>

        <foo class="bar">
          <foo id="ba"></foo>
        </foo>
      </div>
```

Comment: The jQuery OP wrote is fine, the HTML isn't

Comment: @AndyHolmes True ,